# DbContext connection string and hosted service

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a. NET core console app that implement IHostedService and a reference to another project with a DbContext definition.
This is the configuration of DbContext in console app:

```
IHost host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
    {
        configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
        configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
    })
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
{
    configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
    configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true);
    configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true);
    configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
}) 
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddHostedService<ApplicationLifetimeHostedService>();
})
.Build();
```

Now, in the OnStarted() method of ApplicationLifetimeHostedService I have:

```
using (var _context = new MyAppDbContext())
{
    ...
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Why MyAppDbContext take the connection string value from OnConfiguring method of dbcontext definition class (hard-coded, generated from scaffolding), and not from appsettings.{ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMENT}.json ()?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your configuration, currently the `IHostBuilder` is for non web applications and simulates a generic configuration, eventually this will replace the `IWebHostBuilder`.  However, you do not need those...  In your instance you would be better off with `CreateDefaultBuilder`.

- Host Configuration
- App Configuration

Both are provided by default, with more granular control.  The primary item is the default services provided by the builder and what they compile or build.

To directly answer your issue though, in your top line, you are missing the following:

```
 var host = new HostBuilder()
     .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configuration => 
     {
         // For brevity, removed some.
         configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);
     }
```

That is why your `appsettings.json` is not working.  The `ConfigureHostConfiguration` will carry through to the `ConfigureAppConfiguration`.

> Host configuration automatically flows to app configuration
>   (ConfigureAppConfiguration and the rest of the app).
>
> No providers are included by default. You must explicitly specify
>   whatever configuration providers the app requires in
>   ConfigureHostConfiguration, including:
>
> - File configuration (for example, from a hostsettings.json file).
> - Environment variable configuration.
> - Command-line argument configuration.
> - Any other required configuration providers.